# Increment two variables in a loop with a relation between them

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to increment two different variables, in the same for loop or even in nested loops, these two variables are related, one should be less than the other by 10.

Output should look something like this:

**First Iteration:**

> Text1  < First variable/number to increment
>
> > blah blah 1 < Second variable to increment

**Second Iteration**

> Text2
>
> > blah blah 1

**Tenth Iteration**

> Text 10
>
> > blah blah 2

I was unable to write code to do that, I tried to get my head around using nested loops but failed:

> x = [20]

```
for i in range(1, 2000):
   print "Text%d" % (i)
   for j in x:
     print "blah blah%d" % (j)
```

Comment: I don't see how (in your examples) variable 2 is "less than the other by 10"? Do you mean variable2 should be the number of digits in variable1 (`int(math.log10(variable1))+1`)?

Comment: If you remove the inner loop and instead use `j = i // 10`, you may get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you want:

```
for i in xrange(200):
    print "Text%d" % (i)
    print "blah blah %d" % ((i//10) +1)
```